# Captive portal without redirection

Tags: wireless-networking, captive-portal

I am looking to set up an Captive portal which do not provide any pop up to login as soon as the device is connected. Instead, i want the user to bring up the browser and try to load an web page then it should redirect to login page.

I have ddwrt AP and Aruba where i'm not able to achieve the above. Everytime when i connect my phone, throws "sign in reqd" notification.

Answer (score 1):

Modern OSs issue a connection attempt when WLAN comes up to test for connectivity, when your CP redirects that request the machine then knows its behind a CP and triggers the "sign in" dialog.

To prevent this happening you'd need to capture what addresses each OS targets and whitelist them on your captive portal. Maintaining such a list for the four main operating systems (Android, iOS, Windows, OSX) might be burdensome.

Comment: Is there an way to restrict the AP itself to provide http 200 response. So that, we don't get Sign in reqd notification when connected.

Comment: See this answer for details. Seems android looks for specific content in the resp that you would have to send: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123129/how-does-wifi-in-android-detect-if-the-device-has-to-sign-in-or-not